# What are the rules for covering one's head with a talit for sefaradim?

Tags: halacha, minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, tallit-gadol, head

There seems to be a bunch of different minhagim related to covering one's head with a talit. 
My question pertains to sefaradim.

1. Are the rules different for married/non-married?
2. When should you cover?
3. When can you uncover?
4. What is the reason for covering ones head with the talit?

Comment: Rav Eliyahu covered his head, but I've never heard of Rav Yosef A"H doing so. Maybe kabbalistic?